# Bypassing Controller Authentication

Tags: php, logic, codeigniter-2

I'm currently writing a share-once functionality for a logged-in user to send a one-time link to another person (with no prior user account).

At the moment, I have a base controller which verifies user/password credentials, and handles authentication and **all my controllers extend from that base controller**.

**To handle the one-time-share, I:**

- Generate a unique id
- Insert the id with a date field set to NULL in
  the db
- Send the user a link to a controller that takes as parameter
  the unique id
- When the link is accessed, if the unique id exists and
  if the date is NULL then I show the user the correct view and set the
  date field to whatever TIMESTAMP happens to be at that moment.

This works, but...

I have another controller (**/media**), whose task is to retrieve an image from a secure path, and outputs it as an image. In the one-time view, I'm accessing the image like:

```
<img src="/media/image-id" />
```

Because that controller extends from the base controller which handles logins, the one-time user without an account is denied access.

I don't want to lose this level of security, but I'd need to have a way in order to allow the one time users access to the content.

- What approach should I take in order to circumvent controller security for one-time users?

Thank you for any insight!

S.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to say without seeing how you've organized your base controller or the controllers which extend from it. All we could really do is guess. Have you tried making a temporary session that will allow the user to authenticate to base controller? By that I mean, set up a session which limits their access based on what the link is? That way your security system is still being used and you don't have to do any hack work.